# Global replace attribute in prestashop

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

Have prestashop and need global replace some html attributes from all pages (before displaying).

I use extending:

```
protected function smartyOutputContent($content)
```

Some replacing code.

All run good. (But this is not correct rewrite)

But have question, if someone know about some right way how to do it.?
In prestashop, or if some way how correct rewrite some of smarty and extend it...

(ideally if can use it in prestashop module)

Thanks for all ideas.

---

**Change**

In my case, need replace/rename itemprop, itemscope, itemtype. (in module change to json structure)

And want to do ideally, when modul is installed.
But user can had custom theme... So override template is not right way.

I do now:

modules/modul_name/override/classes/controller/Controller.php
With content:

```
protected function smartyOutputContent($content)
{
    $this->context->cookie->write();

    $html = '';
    $js_tag = 'js_def';
    $this->context->smarty->assign($js_tag, $js_tag);

    if (is_array($content)) {
        foreach ($content as $tpl) {
            $html .= $this->context->smarty->fetch($tpl);
        }
    } else {
        $html = $this->context->smarty->fetch($content);
    }

    $html = trim($html);

    if (in_array($this->controller_type, array('front', 'modulefront')) && !empty($html) && $this->getLayout()) {
        $live_edit_content = '';
        if (!$this->useMobileTheme() && $this->checkLiveEditAccess()) {
            $live_edit_content = $this->getLiveEditFooter();
        }

        $dom_available = extension_loaded('dom') ? true : false;
        $defer = (bool)Configuration::get('PS_JS_DEFER');

        if ($defer && $dom_available) {
            $html = Media::deferInlineScripts($html);
        }
        $html = trim(str_replace(array('</body>', '</html>'), '', $html))."\n";

        /* Remove snipped data from attributes html elements */
        $html = str_replace(array('itemprop', 'itemscope', 'itemtype'), 'ip', $html);

        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            $js_tag => Media::getJsDef(),
            'js_files' =>  $defer ? array_unique($this->js_files) : array(),
            'js_inline' => ($defer && $dom_available) ? Media::getInlineScript() : array()
        ));

        $javascript = $this->context->smarty->fetch(_PS_ALL_THEMES_DIR_.'javascript.tpl');

        if ($defer && (!isset($this->ajax) || ! $this->ajax)) {
            echo $html.$javascript;
        } else {
            echo preg_replace('/(?<!\$)'.$js_tag.'/', $javascript, $html);
        }
        echo $live_edit_content.((!isset($this->ajax) || ! $this->ajax) ? '</body></html>' : '');
    } else {
        echo $html;
    }
}
```

All function correct.

Thanks for comment sadlyblue

Comment: This is a little broad of a question. But the best way is to override the function or template file that generates the html tags you what to replace.

Comment: You should sue Google Translator for such a translation. I lost 3 neurons trying to understand this question. Is your problem solved? If not can you try to rephrase your question?